# hector_quadrotor does not take off

Tags: hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS kinetic and since the tutorials on
http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20outdoor%20flight%20demo
is a littile bit out-dated, I followed the answer in
http://answers.ros.org/question/244776/is-it-possible-to-run-the-hector_quadrotor-demos-in-kinetic/.

It did compile and roslaunch the demo successfully. I've checked the rostopic list and found there is actually a topic called /cmd_vel. I tried to use this command to let the quadrotor take-off

```
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

But the quadrotor still stays on the ground. I used

```
rostopic echo /cmd_vel
```

to check if the message is sent to the topic correctly,  and it does.

Does someone know what can be possibly wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256631/hector_quadrotor-does-not-take-off/) by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should first enable motors

rosservice call /enable_motors true

more information in https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/issues/66

---

Originally posted by [danielponsa](https://answers.ros.org/users/30271/danielponsa/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0